# Colinear Complex Solutions

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

For the equation: $m^6=(m-1)^6$

There are 5 distinct complex solutions and I noticed that all of them are colinear in the complex plane, is this a coincidence or is there a theorem behind?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: There can't be $~5~$ distinct complex solutions, because the equation is actually a 5th degree equation, and one of the roots is clearly $~m = 1/2.~$  As a separate consideration, since all of the coefficients of the 5th degree polynomial equation are real, any complex roots must come in *conjugate pairs* (i.e. $~x + iy ~::~x - iy~$).  So there are at most $~4~$ complex roots.

Comment: @user2661923 There are $5$ distinct complex solutions. $1/2$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

If $m\in\mathbb{C}$ is a solution to the equation $m^6=(m-1)^6$ then
\begin{align*}
&
|m^6|=|(m-1)^6|
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|m|^6=|m-1|^6
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|m|^2=|m-1|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m{\overline{m}}
=
(m-1){\overline{m-1}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m{\overline{m}}
=
(m-1)({\overline{m}}-1)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m{\overline{m}}
=
m{\overline{m}}
-
m
-
{\overline{m}}
+
1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m+{\overline{m}}
=
1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{m+{\overline{m}}}{2}
=
\frac{1}{2}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\text{Re}(m)
=
\frac{1}{2}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence all solutions to the equation $m^6=(m-1)^6$ lie on the vertical line $\text{Re}(m)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: very clever, thank you!